# Google maps not rendering with Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am encountering issues with Owl Carousel not rendering on my website. The carousel does not display, and I'm unsure why. Below is the relevant HTML and JavaScript code for initializing Owl Carousel:

```
<!-- Owl Carousel HTML -->
<div class="container">
    <!-- ... (existing HTML content) ... -->

    <div class="carousel-wrap layout_padding2-top">
        <div class="owl-carousel">
            <!-- ... (Owl Carousel items) ... -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Owl Carousel JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

There are no error messages in the console related to Owl Carousel.

Google Maps is not rendering on my website. The map does not display, and there are no error messages in the console. Below is the relevant HTML and JavaScript code for initializing Google Maps:

```html
<!-- Google Maps HTML -->
<div id="googleMap"></div>

<!-- Google Maps JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCh39n5U-4IoWpsVGUHWdqB6puEkhRLdmI&callback=myMap"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

##### Debugging steps

- I have ensured that jQuery, Bootstrap, Owl Carousel, and Google Maps dependencies are correctly loaded.
- I checked the Network tab in my browser's Developer Tools; resources are loaded successfully.
- Verified the content of the `custom.js` file; the script is executed without errors.
- The Google Maps API key is valid and has the necessary permissions.

##### Expected Behavior

I expect both Owl Carousel and Google Maps to render correctly on the webpage.

##### Environment

Browsers tested: Chrome (latest version), Firefox (latest version).
Testing both locally and on a live server.

##### Reproduction Steps

The issue occurs consistently; no specific actions trigger the problem.

##### Complete versions of the code

**`index.html`:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Basic -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <!-- Mobile Metas -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <!-- Site Metas -->
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />

  <title>אלון שירות תיקונים</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />

  <!-- Owl Carousel Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />

  <!-- Your Custom Styles -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  <!-- Owl Carousel JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom Scripts -->
  <script src="scripts/load-content.js"></script>
  <script src="js/custom.js"></script>

  <!-- Google Map API -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCh39n5U-4IoWpsVGUHWdqB6puEkhRLdmI&callback=myMap"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- hero section -->
  <div id="hero-section"></div>
  <!-- end hero section -->

  <!-- features section -->
  <div id="features-section"></div>
  <!-- end features section -->

  <!-- about section -->
  <div id="about-section"></div>
  <!-- end about section -->

  <!-- professional section -->
  <div id="professional-section"></div>
  <!-- end professional section -->

  <!-- service section -->
  <div id="service-section"></div>
  <!-- end service section -->

  <!-- client section -->
  <div id="client-section"></div>
  <!-- end client section -->

  <!-- contact section -->
  <div id="contact-section"></div>
  <!-- end contact section -->

  <!-- info_section -->
  <div id="info-section"></div>
  <!-- end info_section -->

  <!-- footer section -->
  <div id="footer-section"></div>
  <!-- footer section -->

  <!-- Google Map Initialization -->
  <script>
    function myMap() {
      var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712775, -74.005973),
        zoom: 18,
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**My carousel:**

```
<section class="client_section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="heading_container heading_center">
            <h2>
                What Our Clients Say TEST
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-wrap layout_padding2-top ">
            <div class="owl-carousel">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="client_id">
                            <div class="img-box">
                                <img src="images/client-1.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="client_detail">
                                <div class="client_info">
                                    <h6>
                                        Jorch morik
                                    </h6>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </div>
                                <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client_text">
                            <p>
                                chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a
                                dictionary of
                                over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate
                                Lorem Ipsum
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="client_id">
                            <div class="img-box">
                                <img src="images/client-2.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="client_detail">
                                <div class="client_info">
                                    <h6>
                                        Jorch morik
                                    </h6>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </div>
                                <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client_text">
                            <p>
                                chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a
                                dictionary of
                                over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate
                                Lorem Ipsum
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="client_id">
                            <div class="img-box">
                                <img src="images/client-1.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="client_detail">
                                <div class="client_info">
                                    <h6>
                                        Jorch morik
                                    </h6>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </div>
                                <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client_text">
                            <p>
                                chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a
                                dictionary of
                                over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate
                                Lorem Ipsum
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="client_id">
                            <div class="img-box">
                                <img src="images/client-2.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="client_detail">
                                <div class="client_info">
                                    <h6>
                                        Jorch morik
                                    </h6>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </div>
                                <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client_text">
                            <p>
                                chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a
                                dictionary of
                                over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate
                                Lorem Ipsum
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I tried importing the libraries a couple different ways, messed around with `custom.js`, imported `custom.js`.

Comment: Consider editing this to make it make more sense - perhaps some of your formatting attempt(s) have gone bad?

Comment: In your 'complete' HTML the javascript is referencing an element with the id `googleMap` : `document.getElementById("googleMap")`
This element does not appear in the HTML